# XSLT or XPath: how to find a node with a specific tag and text then extract it into a new xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt, extract, inode

I need to find a particular node in an XML file, `<example>Some text</example>`

Then I want to extract this node and it's subelements from the XML file and write it into a new XML file, and then I need to extract the other remaining XML nodes in the original XML file minus the extracted node into the new XML file following the extracted node.

How can I do this with XSLT or XPath?

Answer (score 2):

**Here is how to output all nodes minus the specific node and its subtree**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="example[. = 'Some text']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (none was provided!):

```
<a>
            <example>Some different text</example>
    <b>
        <c>
            <example>Some text</example>
        </c>
            <example>Some other text</example>
    </b>
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c></c>
    </b>
</a>
```

**Here is how to extract only the wanted node and its subtree**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="example[. = 'Some text']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above), the result now is**:

```
<example>Some text</example>
```

**Two different result documents cannot be produced in a single XSLT 1.0 transformation**.

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 transformation that outputs the first result and writes to a file the second result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vResult2">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="result2"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="example[. = 'Some text']"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>

  <xsl:result-document href="file:///c:/temp/delete/result2.xml">
   <xsl:sequence select="$vResult2"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="result2" match="example[. = 'Some text']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="result2" match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: there are several nodes in the source xml with the tag <example> and I need to find a particular <example> node that has the specific text "Some text".  How do I extract only this <example> node with just this specific text "Some text" and not the other <example> nodes?

Comment: @user840930: Please edit the question and provide all relevant information. Next time you are asking a question be more attentive. I updated my answer to reflect your comment.